# Ruby gsub method - accepting hash?

Tags: ruby

Ruby's gsub string method is supposed to accept hash. As written here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185

"If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string."

They give an example:

```
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

Problem is, it's not working for me (ruby 1.8.7):

```
in `gsub': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)
```

This happens for the exact same line. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the doc that OP mentions is for `ruby 1.9.2`. For `ruby 1.8.7`, refer to http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000792; there, `gsub` method does not accept hash as param.

UPDATE:
You can add this feature to your code:

```
class String
  def awesome_gsub(pattern, hash)
    gsub(pattern) do |m| 
      hash[m]
    end
  end
end

p 'hello'.awesome_gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => '3', 'o' => '*') #=> "h3ll*"
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks, @sepp2k. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Ruby 1.9-specific feature.

The Ruby 1.8.7 documentation makes no mention of it: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html

Answer (score 1):

```
"hello".gsub( /([eo])/ ){ {'e' => 3, 'o' => '*'}[$1] }
```

Comment: This is convoluted for the simple hash of the OP, but going through a block could help if you have larger hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/) will enable the 1.9.2 functionality in 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Hash class of your project:

```
# replaces recursively old_value by new_value
def gsub_hash_values(old_value, new_value)
  self.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Array)
      v.each do |vv|
        vv.gsub!(old_value, new_value)
      end
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
      v.gsub_hash_values(old_value, new_value)
    elsif v.respond_to?(:to_s)
     self[k] = v.to_s.gsub(old_value, new_value)
    end
  end
end
```